# Cannot convert float to Decimal: tastypie rendering of Django DecimalField

Tags: django, decimal, tastypie

I have a Django model that includes a DecimalField, which I am trying to expose through a tastypie ModelResource. When I request the tastypie URL, I can't seem to get past this error:

Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string

The stack trace refers to packages/tastypie/fields.py", line 250, around here

```
def convert(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return None

    return Decimal(value)
```

If I exclude this field in the ModelResource definition, the error disappears and the request returns normally (not surprisingly).

I've wondered if I should be explicitly defining a DecimalField in tastypie, but that hasn't been clear to me.

In lower-level python in other situations, I have solved this type of issue by doing Decimal(str(value)). So I tried something like that with dehydrate_FOO on this field called value:

```
def dehydrate_value(self, bundle):
    "for massaging data before it is returned to the client"
    return Decimal(str(bundle.data['value']))
```

But the error persists. I've searched around Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but haven't found many clues. This issue is somewhat related:
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/281

But I do have an updated version of tastypie (v0.9.11).

Any guidance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Python.

Your Python version is < 2.7, no?

Upgrate to python 2.7!

Comment: You are correct. My development VM and almost all our servers run Ubuntu 10.04 with Python 2.6. Probably not possible to use 2.7 until we upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04. Tastypie lists Python requirement as 2.5+, so I thought we would be OK.